# Set a DIV to display 100% width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set a plugin for a gallery on WP site. Grid FX

the gallery should be displaying to 100% of page width. However as content area is restricted to a certain width, all content only display within that confined area. How do I get my gallery to be full page width?

Can anyone help? See the page in question http://laurenfisher.co.uk/fashion/

If you can inspect the elements and advise?

PS - The gallery is shortcode added within a WP page

Thank you

Comment: Take the gallery out of the container and then re-start the container after the gallery div.

Comment: I'd start with that .pagewidth class which is setting a width of 978px.

Comment: Please add your code to the Question so it isn't dependend on the link

Comment: Its a 'shortcode' added to a WP post which makes the gallery appear. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this will make the gallery 100% of the page

```
div.gridfx-items-wrap {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fix. Use the below CSS.

```
div.gridfx {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
```

}

This is just a fix, not an recommended way to do. Ideally you should take the div outside the wrapper.